# Java: could not find or load main class main - not sure why

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit, decompiling

I am trying to upload a **.jar** file onto eclipse in order to be able to edit it.

The purpose of the **.jar** file is to track player coordinates on minecraft.

I have decompiled this **.jar** file on Eclipse, using the **eclipse Java Decompiler**.

However, when I try to run this decompiled code, I am getting the error: **'Could not find or load main class main'**.

This happens when I try to run the 'decompiled code' by creating a run configuration and specify the main class: **'main'**.

I have looked at other forums on this topic and have tried different things without success. However, none of these options have worked.

The decompiled 'main.class' file is currently stored within the **'JRE system library'** folder. Is this the wrong place to store it?

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

I have provided an image of the decompiled code:

[image]

And the run configuration tab, where I specify how I want the code to run.

[image]

Comment: There is no main *method*.  Also, please post code instead of images.

Comment: @AndrewS what method should I specify? :)

Comment: To me this looks like a Decompiled Bukkit plugin. They do not run on their own.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. You tagged "minecraft", so you're probably trying to write a plugin, and those don't necessarily have a main class and intend to be running in the minecraft environment.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich how can I run this bukkit plugin? :)

Comment: To be clear, you want to run a minecraft bukkit server with the Plugin installed?
I have never used bukkit for minecraft servers (I usually use Forge), but you can try to follow this guide: https://bukkit.fandom.com/wiki/Setting_up_a_server . However, I don't know wheter it is up-to-date and still works.

Comment: @LorenzHetterich - why that should affect whether I am able to edit the code using a Java Decompiler on eclipse? :)

Comment: It doesn't but you can't run a plugin for an app on its own, which is what you're trying to do, and which obviously won't work. You need to run minecraft and tell it to include this plugin. Lorenz pointed you to a tutorial.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you for confirming - I will check out that link :)

Comment: I have posted a solution now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have now created a plugin using 'Maven', which allows me to edit the code given that to use Bukkit as an API requires the tool 'Maven'.

https://bukkit.fandom.com/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial_(Eclipse)#Example_Files_and_Templates

Thanks so much for the help :)